# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript code and I get an error that says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Specifically, at the line: `if(inputArray[i].value===resultArray[4]){ ...`

```
var inputArray=[
    document.getElementById("ain")
    ,document.getElementById("ein")
    ,document.getElementById("iin")
    ,document.getElementById("oin")
    ,document.getElementById("uin")];

var ii=0;
while(ii<inputArray.length){
    if(inputArray[i].value===resultArray[4]){
        inputArray[i].style.backgroundColor="yellow";
        alert(resultArray[4]);
    }
    ii++;
}
```

Any advise?

Comment: Where do you define the variable `i`, for `inputArray[i]`?  I see you defined `ii`, not `i`

Comment: You can use a technique called "debugging". Place a breakpoint at the line in error. Then examine the value of the variable `i` and `inputArray[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, you never define the variable `i` which you are using in `inputArray[i]`.  But, beyond that, your code is confusing - you are doing essentially exactly what a `for` loop will do for you, but in a `while` loop, and you're defining some variable `ii` outside of the loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
  if (inputArray[i].value === resultArray[4]) {
    inputArray[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    alert(resultArray[4]);
  }
}
```